# Creating a Table with JPA on wildfly using Hibernate fails

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

Im using JPA to create a table on the built in H2 database of Wildfly 8.0 installation using hibernate, but it fails with the following error message:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare
>   statement     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:581)
>     at test.mdb.MessageDRivenBean.onMessage(MessageDRivenBean.java:41)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [:1.7.0_67]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251)
>     ... 49 more Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not prepare statement   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:89)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
>     ... 74 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Tabelle
>   "JPA_USER" nicht gefunden Table "JPA_USER" not found; SQL statement:
>   insert into JPA_User (employeeId, first_name, last_name, salary)
>   values (null, ?, ?, ?) [42102-173]    at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4864)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4842)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:974)    at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:375)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)     at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:428)  at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:377)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:70)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1076)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:500)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
>     ... 96 more
>
> 19:15:33,694 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server] (Thread-18
>   (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=61b6684a-d6bb-11e4-926e-d9ecaa9f5457-1830325086))
>   HQ222149: Message
>   Reference[55834575461]:RELIABLE:ServerMessage[messageID=55834575461,durable=true,userID=885a963a-dc80-11e4-be97-a7b41dae907c,priority=4,
>   bodySize=256,expiration=0, durable=true,
>   address=jms.queue.demoQueue,properties=TypedProperties[__HQ_CID=8842c877-dc80-11e4-be97-a7b41dae907c]]@400257444
>   has reached maximum delivery attempts, sending it to Dead Letter
>   Address jms.queue.DLQ from jms.queue.demoQueue

The problem seems to be associated with the line Table "JPA_USER" not found; SQL statement:

```
insert into JPA_User (employeeId, first_name, last_name, salary)
values (null, ?, ?, ?) [42102-173]
```

but i want jPA to create the table for me
My persistence.xml looks as follows:

```
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ExampleDS">
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
<properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="sa"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

im using the default datasource, which is associated with the h2 database.

Does anyone know what the problem here might be?

Answer (score 2):

You're property name is incorrect. It's `ddl` not `dll`.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i overlooked that! :)